# Issue to enable SSL in SharePoint 2013 Public Site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, ssl, public-website

I have one Public website on SharePoint 2013. I have added required SSL certificate. But I want to make enable only https url and want to do redirection of http to Https.

I tried it using URL rewriter but In this I can not open SharePoint site on that server it is giving SSL Certificate error.

Can Anyone suggest which is the best way to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can extend the existing web appliation required zone or delete existing site ( only IIS site if http site not required) and extend web application to Default zone with host name and select use SSL option, this will be create IIS site with host name and select proper SSL certificate in IIS bindings.

below is the good article for configure SSL you can refer
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2013/01/20/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior, as the you issued the cert to the URL of the Web application and i am sure you did not included the server name in it(which is best practice). In this case, you can simply ignore the warning and Continue to the web site.

OR you always open the site on your laptop /pc.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has a built in redirect mechanism by using AlternateAccessMappings which is not very well documented.

- Configure your HTTPS URL as only "Public URL for Zone" in Zone "Default":

[image: AlternateAccessMapping]

- Create an IIS-Binding for HTTP and HTTPS

[image: IIS-Bindings]

- SharePoint will now automatically redirect any HTTP request to HTTPS. No need for URL-Rewrite- or Redirect-Module in IIS.