# Remove Old Alternate Access Mapping URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis, alternate-access-mapping

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm (2 WFE, 1 APP, 2 DB) that was accessible on the internal network via http://sharepoint.  I have since setup SSL in IIS and in Central Administration changed all the Alternate Access Mapping URLs and Web Application URLs that I could find to https://sharepoint.example.com.  This is all working.

My problem is that I get entries in the Application log that

> Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site https://sharepoint.example.com with the URL http://sharepoint.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL http://sharepoint as an AAM response URL.  For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=114854

Where can I look to remove the old non-https link?

Edit 1:

Alternate Access Mappings
AAM settings are...

```
Internal URL                             Zone      Public URL for Zone
https://sharepoint.example.com           Default   https://sharepoint.example.com
https://app.sharepoint.example.com       Default   https://sharepoint.example.com
https://app.sharepoint.example.com:8080  Default   https://app.sharepoint.example.com:8080
https://app.sharepoint.example.com:8081  Default   https://app.sharepoint.example.com:8081
https://app.sharepoint.example.com:8082  Default   https://app.sharepoint.example.com:8082

:8080 is MySites
:8081 is Central Administration
:8082 is MetaLogix ControlPoint
```

Comment: Whats your AAM settings?

Comment: I'll add AAM settings to my original post for better formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this behavior several times and never found the spot where SharePoint "remembers" the old URL.

But there's a nice workaround:

- You should now have configured your new FQDN URL `https://sharepoint.example.com` in the AAM-Zone `Default`
- Add the old URL `http://sharepoint` to a new AAM in any free zone (like `Intranet`)
- Also add an IIS-Binding for your old URL
- SharePoint should now work fine. You might see some references to the old URL in your ULS-Logs.
- Wait some weeks or even months. SharePoint now should have completely forgotten the old URL. It's safe now to remove the old URL in AAM and IIS-Bindings

Bonus:

- Looks like you switched from HTTP to HTTPs. [Implement a HTTP to HTTPS redirect](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238516/issue-to-enable-ssl-in-sharepoint-2013-public-site/238871#238871) for your internal users for increased convenience.

Comment: There's a requirement that HTTP be converted to HTTPS.  Thus I currently have two IIS bindings, and am using a URL Rewrite to redirect everything to the HTTPS FQDN URL.  Eventually (like, yesterday) I'll need to remove this binding as well.

When I add http://sharepoint as a AAM, it lists http://sharepoint as the Public URL for Zone as well... how do I get the Public URL for Zone to be https://sharepoint.example.com?

Comment: Use the "add internal URL" button in AAM-Dialog. Select the correct WebApplication and make sure you have "Default" Zone selected. Enter `http://sharepoint` in "URL" field. Then in should look like in my linked article. And do not forget the IIS-Binding for `http://sharepoint`.

Comment: I think it was the http:// binding.  I have not seen the Application event long entry since I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your "Default" Zone Alternate Access Mapping to:

```
httpS://SharePoint.Example.com
```

From

```
http://SharePoint
```

This maybe causing the issue. I would change the "Default" Zone back to:

```
http://SharePoint
```

Then I would add as a "Custom" Zone or other free zone(s) i.e. as an "Internet" Zone

```
httpS://SharePoint.Example.com 
httpS://SharePoint
```

Make sure to check in IIS that the host header bindings are set for:

```
httpS://SharePoint.Example.com
httpS://SharePoint
    Typically on port 443
```

Here is a PS Script to Add AAM's:

```
New-SPAlternateURL –WebApplication "http://SharePoint" -URL "httpS://SharePoint.Example.com" –Zone Custom
```

Here is a basic article on AAM's in SharePoint 2013 (Alternate Access Mappings):
http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/07/add-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/configure-alternate-access-mappings

Hope this helps!